# Comprehensive list of possible fields in APA6

Tags: database, apa6, data-structures

I'm coming into a situation where users have uploaded thousands of documents (all non-published).  There are only basic elments stored currently, including Title, Author, Year.   Some fields contain additional data.

I need to rewrite this form to better categorize the documents so that I can eventually generate a reference list in APA6.

I'm familiar with the fields needed for APA6 published lit (such as from Pubmed), however there are many other possible document types including pamphlets, web page, email, ect.

Is there a comprehensive list of document types (and/or fields) that one might run across in APA6 styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apa6` documentation says in section 6.5:

> The apa6 class supports three bibliography packages: biblatex, apacite, and natbib.

The `biblatex` approach is documented in `biblatex-apa.pdf` and the references therein.  The `natbib` option loads the `apacite` package, and both variations are documented in `apacite.pdf` and the references therein.  These documents are on CTAN, texdoc.net and probably installed on your system, e.g. accessible via `texdoc apa6`, `texdoc biblatex-apa`, etc.